# Ajax call does not go into the success handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is a scenario that I am stuck at:

**What I have**

A MVC ActionResult that's returning a Json:

```
public ActionResult GetUpdates(string productId)
{
    var updatesForProduct = _repository.GetUpdates(productId);

    if (updatesForProduct.Count != 0)
    {
        return Json(
                     new
                     {
                         UpdatedData = updatesForProduct.Select(x => new[] 
                        { 
                           x.UpdatedDate.ToString(),
                           x.NewLabel
                        })
                     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

The JS part:

```
function GetProductUpdate() {

    var urlToGetProductUpdate = "/Products/GetUpdates/"

    var request = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: urlToGetProductUpdate,
        method: "GET",
        data: { productId: productId},
        dataType: "JSON"
    });

    request.done(function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            console.log(result);
        }
        else {
            alert("Not able to get Updates!");
        }

    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        alert("Request failed.");
    });
}
```

**What's happening:**

I can see in the debugger that that the call to the repository returns a list of updates and in the JS it does go into the .done promise but inside it's going to the alert part instead of success as I expect it to be.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning a success property in your JSON when the update occures, only when you don't update anything.
If you put a console.log(result) at the beginning of the *done*:

```
request.success(function (result) {
   console.log(result);
   if (result.success) {
        console.log(result);
   }
   else {
       alert("Not able to get Updates!");
   }
});
```

the success property should not be found, only the result you send as JSON:

> { UpdatedData: [{ UpdatedDate: "...", NewLabel: "..." }] }

You should probably have a property in your JSON result, so that your controller action looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetUpdates(string productId)
{
    var updatesForProduct = _repository.GetUpdates(productId);

    if (updatesForProduct.Count > 0)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, updatedData = 
            updatesForProduct.Select(x => new[] 
                { 
                    x.UpdatedDate.ToString(),
                    x.NewLabel
                })
             }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { success = false }); //not sure if this should be true or false in your case
}
```

**Sidenote:**

You should remove the

```
async: false,
```

as you are using deferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request.success(function (result) {
    console.log(result.success);        
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Define the functions for success and fail inside the ajax definition:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: urlToGetProductUpdate,
    method: "GET",
    data: { productId: productId},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data, status, jqxhr)
    {
        \\logging
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, status, errotMsg)
    {
        \\ alert
    }
});
```